# how to make sure the dependent and independent variables measure the same thing?

Tags: regression, correlation, graph-theory

I am trying to build a model that measures the importance of musicians social network on their number of gigs. I use graph theory and construct the social network based on the line-up of events for each artist. In another word, if two musicians appear at the same festival, I draw an edge between them (co-gig network). Each node(i.e.artists) in this network can be described by several features. For example degree centrality of a node count the number of edges connected to it. The higher degree means the higher number of exposure to another node. I want to use these features as my independent variable. These variables capture the position and importance of a node in this network. I use number of gigs as my dependent variable.

I am thinking about constructing a panel that contains the trajectory of the artists career. The format would be something as follow:

$artist_1 \quad career_t\quad  iv1_t\quad  iv2_t\quad  ...\quad iv10_t 
\quad ngigs_{(t+1)}\\
artist_2 \quad career_t\quad  iv1_t\quad  iv2_t\quad  ...\quad iv10_t \quad ngigs_{(t+1)}\\...\\...$

Where $t$ starts from 1 to the career length of each artist. I used this model to understand how the current social network of an artist can explain her success in the next year of her career. I am thinking to use the GEE regression.

The problem is that both dependent and independent variables have extracted based on the gigs history of an artist. Using a degree as an example, an artist that has appeared in many festivals is more likely to have a higher degree. So maybe degree itself can be used as my dependent variable. When I compute the correlation between degree and the number of gigs, I get the high value of 0.8.

I found two threads on the similar topics but I think the question is slightly different. 
[a high correlation coefficient between the dependent variable and a control variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/221247/a-high-correlation-coefficient-between-the-dependent-variable-and-a-control-vari)
https://www.researchgate.net/post/When_there_is_high_correlation_between_independent_and_dependent_variables_how_can_I_prove_discriminant_validity_of_them

Someone suggested me to use structural equation modeling to account for the correlation between variables, but since I am not familiar with this model I wanted to make sure if it's the right direction before diving into it.

Comment: What's your hypothesis you want to test? Indeed as I understood the only reason why the correlation isn't one is artists having multiple gigs with the same other artists, so that's basically what your measuring indirectly.

Comment: You've said what the co-gig network is. You have not said what the ego network is, nor which variables are your dependent and independent variables.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "handle this issue"?  What kind of statistical analysis or activity would that correspond to?